# Job is failing because of temp space getting full

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, oracle12c, database-administration

Our `customer` is loading data of last 3 years in one new reporting product. It has millions of record. Our intermediate `query` is producing `964M` record and at this stage `job` is getting failed due to `insufficient temp storage`. They increased temp space thrice. Our `query plan` and `joins` are proper

My Question is.

1. Can we give them some estimate that for billion record you need this number of `data file` in your `temp` `tablespace`.
2. Is it possible to calculate the above statistics? as I talked with some experts and they said capacity planning is not possible.

I know records are huge and they may need to change hardware as well. But is there anything we can suggest them to change at memory level and if possible hardware level.

If you want I can attach `explain plan` and `trace here`.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68301326/266304)

Comment: Yes ALex. Only I put that question. I thought I can frame question in some better way and can look for some specific information so I put. by the way both problem can be different sometimes.

Comment: The "explain plan" you posted on your previous question was a trace, not the output of the `EXPLAIN PLAN` command. A proper explain plan will give an estimate on how many bytes of data will be involved with each step, and which steps will involve writes to the TEMP tablespace. As requested on your previous question, use the `EXPLAIN PLAN` command to generate the plan and post those results. Note that this is still only an estimate, but it should at least give you a ballpark idea of what you're looking at.

Comment: Ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/  . And, get your database administrator and the vendor of the "new reporting product" to help you. It seems unlikely you'll be able to program around this without altering the reporting product's code.

Comment: Throwing temp space at the problem isn't the best solution.    Anything using massive temp space would make me look at more efficient ways of achieving this.   I will post on your original post about ideas about reducing temp space but as everyone says you need to look at the explain plan to see where the temp usage is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pmdba noted, an EXPLAIN PLAN will assist with an estimate of the temp space required, but that is strictly an estimate. Notice that your execution plan has many nested hash joins, and thus you can easily get a compounding of temp space needs, because a multiple hash joins can be "active", (ie, one has commenced but requires the output of an inner one).

But assuming this is a one time load, I would propose a different approach for your DBAs. Simply create a new temp tablespace with either a bigfile or many datafiles with a massive autoextend allowance.  If necessary, put it on scratch/throwaway disk.  Allocate just this user account to it, then run your load and just let the temp space grow to whatever size it needs.

Once your load is done, drop the tablespace and resume normal operations. A massive temp doesn't make any difference to your database - it doesn't get backed up, its contents don't need logging.