# instead of hash join forcing optimizer for use_nl

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, database-administration

My query is failing because out of `temp storage` . We increased many times but its not working. I have checked the `trace` it is making `hash join` with most of the tables. Since we have `indexed` defined on the `table` can we force optimizer to `use nested loop join`?
My thought process is:-

1. it wont make `Hash table` so we can easily save that space in `temp` storage. since it has around 964 M rows so I am thinking if we can do that?
2. It will not read all the data from inner table since it has `indexes` so query can become fast.

I can be 100% incorrect but since we are not able to come with solution so looking for validations and help. Any additional , comment or help would be highly helpful.

If need I can attach the `trace`. since it so long so I am not attaching as of now.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, please provide us with an execution plan at least please

Comment: You need to provide your query plan. Without it it is hard to tell if some additional structures will or will not help. But 900M index lookups is not what sounds like a performance improvement.

Comment: Thank you so much. Plan I have attached here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301326/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-by-128-in-tables

Comment: Your literal question is "yes, you can force Oracle to change the join method".  I believe that your actual question is whether or not changing the join method is likely to cause performance issues which is a much larger question.  Please don't just link to another question where more information about the problem-- you'll need to edit this question to include the actual question (assuming I'm right about what you're actually asking) and to include enough information (like the query plan) for the question to be self-contained.

Comment: you still put the trace output not an explain plan.
You can add a hint to use nested loops (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-56DAA0EC-54BB-4E9D-9049-BCEA934F7A89) but I suspect it might solve your temp space issue but cause you performance issues.

As mentioned in one of your other posts, I think you need to look at your query and optimize that rather than trying to avoid it using temp space